# latexmk clean (-c): some Beamer-related files are not deleted

Tags: latexmk

I'm trying to use `latexmk -c` (or `latexmk -C`) to clean a directory, but when I run any of these two commands, I get the following:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 21 May 2019, version: 4.64a.
Latexmk: Disallowing switch of output file as incompatible
    with file requests.
```

The "Disallowing switch..." message seems to be related to the `-pdf` option. If added (as in, `latexmk -c -pdf`), the message disappears, and there are no visible effects on the amount of deleted files.

I have a `main.tex` which contains Beamer code, and when I run `latexmk -pdf main.tex`, the following files are produced (besides `main.pdf` itself):

```
main.fdb_latexmk
main.fls
main.log
main.nav
main.out
main.snm
main.toc
main.vrb
```

If I run `latexmk -c`, most of the files are cleaned, but the following remain:

```
main.nav
main.snm
main.vrb
```

How can I remove these Beamer-related files using latexmk?

Comment: exactly how are you running the command? I normally run it as `latexmk -c file.tex` to clean everything related to `file.tex`

Comment: I supposed just running `latexmk -c` without arguments would suffice, removing `*.aux` and similar files. However, even if I run `latexmk -c main.tex`, I get the same result.

Comment: Interesting, exactly which version are you running (`latexmk -version`) and which operating system? Using 4.65 on linux `latexmk -c` with no args works fine.

Comment: I posted an answer from what I realized, the warning threw me off but it does not affect the behavior. I believe a feature request for latexmk to include `vrb`, `snm` and `nav` files would be helpful.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I changed the question, so you can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Just to reinforce the information about the warning message:  It's purely informational, and can be ignored here.  See the section "ALLOWING FOR CHANGE OF OUTPUT FILE TYPE" in the `latexmk` documentation to understand what it's about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

latexmk has an internal list of extensions that are known to be safe to delete. But it does not know all extensions used by all LaTeX packages or which of them are safe to delete.

latexmk can read configuration files (you'll have to look up where they are located for your self), in there you can give a space separated list of save extensions for `latexmk -c` to delete. I have the following in my global `latexmkrc`:

```
$clean_ext = "synctex.gz nav snm thm soc loc glg acn";
```

Latexmk manual: https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html (not sure how up to date it is, but it does mention the locations of the configuration files)

Comment: I have kept the `.latexmkrc` file in my project directory. It working properly on the directory, but not on the sub-directories. What should I change to enable it in the subdirectories too?

Comment: @raf your question is not related to this answer, please post your own question. Note that I keep mine in the root of my home directory or use a custom one via `-r file.rc`

Comment: It is worth noting that `clean_ext` defines _additional_ extensions to what is built into latexmk. As your example shows, you don't need to put in things like `.aux` or `.toc` etc.